# Telnet scripting for e-mail address verification

Tags: validation, batch-file, telnet

I have a list of e-mails which I want to verify if the elements are real or not.
I found out I can use telnet via cmd to do so as follows:

```
nslookup -q=mx gmail.com
telnet 'choose an adress from previous feedback' 25
helo hi (saluting the server)
mail from:'a valid mail adress'
rcpt to:'the e-mail address i want to check if it's real or not'
```

My question is if I can somehow do this using a script of some sort. Let's say I write a batch file with all the instructions and e-mails I have. How could I work that out? Any ideea would be appreciated.

Comment: The windows telnet client is not scriptable. But if you Google Search you will find one that has that functionality.

Answer (score 0):

PHP has a number of functions to check DNS information, like [getmxrr()](http://php.net/getmxrr) will get the MX records for a given host name, although it can return empty, an array with a NULL, an invalid and unroutable IP address, or something else, which would may not even be useful to check.

Further more, few, if any, email servers will allow you to validate that an email address exists like this anyway - so it really won't work.

The only 'gold standard' way to confirm that an email address exists, is to send an email to it, and have a unique URL be visited to prove that it was received.